# vue-plupload : upload issus multiple files with multiple component plupload in only one form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plupload

I use view-plupload for a project.
Vue-plupload is itself included in another component.

```
<template>
    <div class="plupload" :id="unique_id">
        <input readonly="readonly" type="text" class="form-control input-sm can-upload" :value="DocumentFile.FileName">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <vue-plupload :id="unique_id" class="upl-add btn new-btn-erdf btn-sm"  
                @uploaded="handleUploaded"
                @added="handleAdded" 
                :options.sync="defaultoptions" 
                :text="textDefaut">
            </vue-plupload>
            <a v-if="DocumentFile.FileName  === ''" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="height:35px;" target="_blank"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></i></a>
            <button v-else class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="pickFile" style="height:35px;" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'plupload',
        props: ['value', 'DocumentFile'],
        watch: {
            value(nv) {
                console.log('NV = ', nv);
                this.setValue(nv);
            }
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                uploadInfo: {},
                unique_id: '',
                defaultoptions: {
                    url: "/DemandeRaccordement/HandleUpload",
                    multi_selection: false,
                    unique_names: true,
                    multiple_queues: false,
                    browse_button : 'pickfiles', 

                    runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
                    filters: {
                        mime_types: [
                            { title: "Documents acceptes", extensions: "jpg,jpeg,pdf,xlsm" }
                        ]
                    },
                    flash_swf_url: '/Scripts/plupload/Moxie.swf'
                },
                textDefaut: 'Joindre'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            handleAdded: function (uploader, file, result) {
                uploader.start();
            },
            handleUploaded: function (uploader, file, result) {
                this.setValue($.parseJSON(result.response));
            },
            setValue(val) {
                this.DocumentFile.FileName = val.FileName
                this.DocumentFile.Url = val.Url
            }
        },
        computed: {
            $$el() {
                return $(this.$el).children('.can-upload');
            },
        },
        created: function(){
            this.unique_id = Date.now();
        }
    }
</script>
```

On my form, I have to have several times the same component 'view-plupload' because I have different files to upload.

[image]

For example, in this image, 
I uploaded the file from the plupload component on the left and yet it is the one on the right that retrieves the values.

Same thing in my props, I have two props Plan1 and Plan2. When I upload with Plan1, the values will go into Plan2.

I tried to add a unique identifier but I have trouble taking ... I thought that it came from that !?

I have simply no error message, the information does not go into the good props of the right component.
It is as if I put several times the component view-plupload but that this one is only initialized once (the last time)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please include the relevant code to the post (i.e create a [mcve]) to keep it consistent through time ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not do more ... it's a professional job.

I can not give more than what there is with the link.

To reproduce the [My Code](https://codeshare.io/5ze9ob) use 

[vue-plupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-plupload) 

 by trying to put several occurrences and see if it works.

Thank you

Comment: Yes you can: I've just did it!

Comment: Thanks for that.
If not any idea to help me?